# cURL request converting "htmlentities" in the URL query string

Tags: php, curl

The URL I'm sending contains a query variable named `timeslot_start`:

```
$URL='https://api.example.com/endpoint?timeslot_start=gte_1600749639';
```

The result contains a parameter for the "next" url (`page=2` added to query string).

When I make a regular cURL request on the command line, the url looks like I expect:

```
https://api.example.com/endpoint?timeslot_start=gte_1600749639&page=2
```

But when I make it in php:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
curl_close ($ch);
```

Somewhere along the line, `&times` is getting converted to `x`:

```
https://api.example.com/endpoint?xlot_start=gte_1600749639&page=2
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Don't put your arguments in the url itself, use whatever is the PHP equivalent of `-d name=value` (one for each name=value pair)

Comment: The only context in which I can imagine that happening, is HTML. A browser might interpret `&times` to mean the multiplication character, `×` – despite that “entity” missing a trailing semicolon to begin with. But in the example URL you have given, you don’t even have `&times`, you have `?times` … So far, this is anything but clear. At which point are you actually running into this problem?

Comment: @04FS you are correct. It is only when I print the returned URL to the screen that the HTML entity is converted. When I log it to a file, it looks as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was only in my viewing of the query string that the conversion occurred.

When I printed the URL (and query string) that was returned by the API to the screen, `$timeslot_start` was converted to `xlot_start`.

I spent quite some time digging through the Wordpress codebase:

```
1. `wp_post_request` calls
2. `class-http.php` methods
3. `class-request.php` methods
```

Finally someone above in a comment helped me realize that it was only within the HTML that I was viewing the data, that it was being corrupted.

Writing the data out to a file:

```
/**
 * Helper function to write strings or arrays to a file
 *
 * @since     1.0.1
 *
 * @param $message the content to be written to file.
 * @param $file_path string optional path to write file to.
 */
public function log($message, $file_path='')
{
    $file_path = ( ($file_path == '') || !file_exists($file_path) ) ? WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/mobilize_america.log' : $file_path;
    $header = date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A', strtotime("now")) . "\t ";

    // Just keep up to seven days worth of data
    if (file_exists($file_path)){
        if (time() - filemtime($file_path) >= 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) { // 7 days
            unlink($file_path);
        }
    }

    if (is_array($message) || is_object($message)) {
        $message = print_r($message, true);
    }
    $message .= "\n";
    file_put_contents(
        $file_path,
        $header . $message,
        FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
    );
}
```

I realized that the return URL was in fact fine, and that I was messing up the query_string I was *sending* by running `htmlentities()` on it before sending.